# Fizz Buzz to Text

Tags: code-golf, binary

## Introduction

I don't *particularly* know where the fizz buzz trend came from. It might just be a meme or something, but it is somewhat popular.

## Challenge

Your job today is to convert Fizz Buzz into binary (0, 1) respectively, and convert that binary to text. Pretty standard stuff.

## How does that work?

FizzBuzzBuzzFizzBuzzFizzFizzFizz FizzBuzzBuzzFizzBuzzFizzFizzBuzz would translate into 01101000 01101001 then that would translate into "hi"

## Constraints

- Input is Fizz Buzz in a binary standpoint (see examples below.)
- Output must be text.
- You can assume the FizzBuzz input is right.
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), shortest bytes win.

## Input

> FizzBuzzBuzzFizzBuzzFizzFizzFizz FizzBuzzBuzzFizzBuzzFizzFizzBuzz FizzFizzBuzzFizzFizzFizzFizzBuzz

## Output

"hi!"

Comment: Meme? This is a primary (elementary) school game

Comment: Can we not take spaces in the input?

Comment: The only space allowed in the input is the space between letters in the word.

Comment: Can we not take that space though? I can save three bytes if I don't have to input that space.

Comment: No. @HyperNeutrino

Comment: So every 8 bits make up one character? Will the first bit always be 0?

Comment: 8 bits per character. As for the first bit being 0, yes.

Comment: Can we output an array of individual characters?

Comment: No, full string.

Comment: Incidentally, this actually has nothing to do with the game of FizzBuzz, that has been around much longer than the internet has.

Comment: I think by calling it a meme just made it a meme. Thanks for your contribution.

Comment: FizzBuzz enjoys a lot of currency on Stack Exchange in part because Joel (one of the founders) had [a blog post referencing another blog which talked about using it as a low barrier to entry problem for programming applicants](https://blog.codinghorror.com/why-cant-programmers-program/).

Comment: @dmckee the "another blog" that Joel references is Jeff Atwood's, the other founder of Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 55):

### C, 59 bytes

```c
i;f(char*s){while(*s&3?*s&9||(i+=i+*s%5):putchar(i),*s++);}
```

Magic numbers, magic numbers everywhere!

(Also, C shorter than Python, JS, PHP, and Ruby? Unheard of!)

This is a function that takes a string as input and outputs to STDOUT.

#### Walkthrough

The basic structure is:

```c
i;           // initialize an integer i to 0
f(char*s){
while(...);  // run the stuff inside until it becomes 0
}
```

Here, the "stuff inside" is a bunch of code followed by `,*s++`, where the comma operater returns only the value of its second argument. Hence, this will run through the string and set `*s` to every character, including the trailing NUL byte (since postfix `++` returns the previous value), before exiting.

Let's take a look at the rest:

```c
*s&3?*s&9||(i+=i+*s%5):putchar(i)
```

Peeling away the ternary and short circuiting `||`, this can be expanded to

```c
if (*s & 3) {
    if (!(*s & 9)) {
        i += i + *s % 5;
    }
} else {
    putchar(i);
}
```

Where do these magic numbers come from? Here are the binary representations of all the characters involved:

```c
F  70  01000110
B  66  01000010
i  105 01101001
z  122 01111010
u  117 01110101
   32  00100000
\0 0   00000000
```

First, we need to separate space and NUL from the rest of the characters. The way this algorithm works, it keeps an accumulator of the "current" number, and prints it whenever it reaches a space or the end of the string (i.e. `'\0'`). By noticing that `' '` and `'\0'` are the only characters to not have any of the two least significant bits set, we can bitwise AND the character with `0b11` to get zero if the character is space or NUL and nonzero otherwise.

Digging deeper, in the first "if" branch, we now have a character that's one of `FBizu`. I chose only to update the accumulator on `F`s and `B`s, so I needed some way to filter out the `izu`s. Conveniently, `F` and `B` both have only the second, third, or seventh least significant bits set, and all the other numbers have at least one other bit set. In fact, they all have either the first or fourth least significant bit. Hence, we can bitwise AND with `0b00001001`, which is 9, which will yield 0 for `F` and `B` and nonzero otherwise.

Once we've determined that we have an `F` or `B`, we can map them to `0` and `1` respectively by taking their modulus 5, because `F` is `70` and `B` is `66`. Then the snippet

```c
i += i + *s % 5;
```

is just a golfy way of saying

```c
i = (i * 2) + (*s % 5);
```

which can also be expressed as

```c
i = (i << 1) | (*s % 5);
```

which inserts the new bit at the least significant position and shifts everything else over 1.

"But wait!" you might protest. "After you print `i`, when does it ever get reset back to 0?" Well, `putchar` casts its argument to an `unsigned char`, which just so happens to be 8 bits in size. That means everything past the 8th least significant bit (i.e. the junk from previous iterations) is thrown away, and we don't need to worry about it.

Thanks to [@ETHproductions](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/42545/ethproductions) for suggesting to replace `57` with `9`, saving a byte!

Comment: Nice trick with the putchar.

Comment: This is reeeeeally awesome. C did right!

Comment: Speaking of doing things right, this is, in my not-so-humble opinion, how a code-golf answer should be done. You post a clever, insightful solution, accompanied by a complete, well-written explanation that actually teaches people something about the language that might be useful in other, more practical circumstances.

Comment: @CodyGray Exactly this. One of the reasons that Code Golf isn't on the top of my SE that I visit frequently is because a lot of answers are just "here's the code". While that's cool for people who are very familiar with the languages, it just looks like noise to me. I like to see the explanations like here because it reveals the *method*, which I would think most people find a lot more interesting than the code itself. Just my two cents...

Comment: Very nice bithack, but you count your bits from MSB(left) to LSB(right)?  IMO the only sane way to count bits in an 8-bit byte (or a 128-bit SIMD vector, or whatever) is from LSB=bit 0 to MSB=bit 7.

Comment: Also, calling this function a second time continues the sequence, instead of starting a new one, because `i` lives in static storage.  I guess you can call that a feature: lets you work in chunks instead of being limited to strings that fit in memory :P

Comment: @PeterCordes You've got a point. Fixed that :P As for your second comment, there will be no observable effect if the function has been run before for the same reason as that mentioned in the second to last paragraph.

Comment: @Doorknob: oh right, that's true if the input has 8 "bits" before the first space.  I guess your function is assuming groups of 8 anyway, since it doesn't reset `i` after printing.  The question doesn't mention that case, so presumably it doesn't need to be handled.  (But if it did, there's a question of whether to treat the whole thing as a bitstring like you do, or whether each space-separated group should be padded out to become the low bits of a full byte.)

Answer (score 10):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 9 bytes

```
Ḳm€4O%5ḄỌ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#@/9wx6bcR01rTPxVTR/uaHm4u@f///9umVVVTqUQDGODaBhWwKcAxFZA5iDrhIkBAA)

Comment: Oh smart, flattening it was unnecessary. Nice.

Comment: @HyperNeutrino Note the comment I've made on yours, I've used a slightly different algorithm so as to avoid duping (even though technically allowed I don't like it).

Comment: @downvoter: did you test this at all before drive-by downvoting?

Answer (score 9):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>169</s> <s>101</s> <s>93</s> <s>91</s> <s>85</s> 81 bytes

```python
lambda s,j="".join:j(chr(int(j('01'[b<"C"])for b in c[::4]),2))for c in s.split())
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fZhvzPycxNyklUaFYJ8tWSUkvKz8zzypLIzmjSCMzr0QjS0PdwFA9OslGyVkpNi2/SCFJITNPITnaysokVlPHSFMTJJYMEivWKy7IySzR0NT8X1AE0poGNKCgFCSg@d8ts6rKqRSCYWwQDcMK@BSA2ArIHGSdMDEA)

Explanation:

```python
lambda s,j="".join:  # Create a lambda function
    j(  # call "".join, adds characters together with nothing in between
        chr(  # character by int
            int(  # string to int
                j(  # "".join again
                    '01'[b<"C"]  # 1 or 0, based on what character we get
                    for b in c[::4]  # For every first of 4 characters
                ),
                2)  # Base 2
        )
        for c in s.split()  # for every group of Fizz and Buzz with any whitespace character after it
    )
```

Comment: That was fast. +1

Comment: I did something similar to this a while ago, it was just a matter of copy-paste and change it to FizzBuzz :P

Comment: Oh that explains. :P But you got outgolfed ;_;

Comment: Outgolfed by about 70-150 bytes

Comment: [you can insert the print inside the list](https://tio.run/nexus/python3#@19QlJlXoqGkpJeVn5mnEZ2cUaSBLFBcAuEn2Sg5K2lqpuUXKSQpZOYpJEdbWZnEauoYQcSSQWKZeQWlJRqaesUFOZlAOlZT8/9/t8yqKqdSCIaxQTQMK@BTAGIrIHOQdcLEAA)

Comment: **[Outgolfed again - Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/P8tWSUkvKz8zz7qgKDOvRCNLIzmjSAPCKi6BsJJslJyVNDXT8osUkhQy8xSSo62sTGI1dYwgYskgscy8gtISDU294oKcTCCtqfn/v1tmVZVTKQTD2CAahhXwKQCxFZA5yDphYgA)** (89 bytes)

Comment: Whoops, **[did it again](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fZhvzPycxNyklUaFYJ8tWSUkvKz8zzypLIzmjSCMzr0QjS6O4BMJKslFyVtLUTMsvUkhSyMxTSI62sjKJ1dQxgoglg8SK9YoLcjJLNDQ1/xcUgTSlAbUWlIIENP@7ZVZVOZVCMIwNomFYAZ8CEFsBmYOsEyYGAA)**, 85 bytes this time with a `lambda` function

Comment: [81 bytes](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fZhvzPycxNyklUaFYJ8tWSUkvKz8zzypLIzmjSCMzr0QjS0PdwFA9OslGyVkpNi2/SCFJITNPITnaysokVlPHSFMTJJYMEivWKy7IySzR0NT8X1AE0poGNKCgFCSg@d8ts6rKqRSCYWwQDcMK@BSA2ArIHGSdMDEA)

Answer (score 9):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/) + coreutils, <s>61</s> 50 bytes

*(-11 bytes thanks to [Doorknob](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/3808/doorknob)!)*

```bash
tr -d izu<<<$1|tr FB 01|dc -e'2i?[aPz0<k]dskx'|rev
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/v6RIQTdFIbOq1MbGRsWwBsh1c1IwMKxJSVbQTVU3yrSPTgyoMrDJjk0pzq5QrylKLfv/3y2zqsqpFIJhbBANwwr4FIDYCsgcZJ0wMTpY8TUvXzc5MTkjFQA)

Comment: You can replace the `sed` with `tr FB 01|tr -d izu` to save 11 bytes.

Answer (score 8):

### JavaScript (ES6), <s>80</s> 79 bytes

```js
let f =

s=>`${s} `.replace(/.{4} ?/g,m=>m[s=s*2|m<'F',4]?String.fromCharCode(s&255):'')

console.log(f("FizzBuzzBuzzFizzBuzzFizzFizzFizz FizzBuzzBuzzFizzBuzzFizzFizzBuzz FizzFizzBuzzFizzFizzFizzFizzBuzz"))
```

Comment: Very nice. I tried and failed to come up with something shorter, though there are several alternate 80-byte solutions using `.replace(/..zz/g,`, `'0b'+`, etc.

Comment: @ETHproductions Getting rid of `n` allows to reach 79. Sadly, this requires an extra space to be added to the input. Hence the rather costly `\`${s} \` `.

Answer (score 7):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), <s>26</s> <s>24</s> <s>19</s> 17 bytes

```
¸®ë4 ®c u5Ãn2 dÃq
```

[Try it online!](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.4&code=uK7rNCCuYyB1NcNuMiBkw3E=&input=IkZpenpCdXp6QnV6ekZpenpCdXp6Rml6ekZpenpGaXp6IEZpenpCdXp6QnV6ekZpenpCdXp6Rml6ekZpenpCdXp6IEZpenpGaXp6QnV6ekZpenpGaXp6Rml6ekZpenpCdXp6IiAtUQ==)

Saved 2 bytes thanks to [@Shaggy](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/58974/shaggy) & 2 bytes thanks to [@ETHproductions](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/42545/ethproductions)

#### Explanation

```
input: "FizzBuzzBuzzFizzBuzzFizzFizzFizz FizzBuzzBuzzFizzBuzzFizzFizzBuzz FizzFizzBuzzFizzFizzFizzFizzBuzz"

¸®                // ["FizzBuzzBuzzFizzBuzzFizzFizzFizz","FizzBuzzBuzzFizzBuzzFizzFizzBuzz","FizzFizzBuzzFizzFizzFizzFizzBuzz"]
  ë4              // ["FBBFBFFF","FBBFBFFB","FFBFFFFB"]
     ®c           // [[70,66,66,70,66,70,70,70],[70,66,66,70,66,70,70,66],[70,70,66,70,70,70,70,66]]
        u5Ã       // ["01101000","01101001","00100001"]
           n2     // [104,105,33]
              d   // ["h","i","!"]
               Ãq // "hi!"
```

Comment: You can replace the 2 `})` with `Ã`. There's definitely more to be saved than that but I can't quite get it working on my phone.

Comment: Very nice, thanks for using Japt! You can save a couple bytes by replacing `ò4...q n2` with `ë4...n2` (`ë4` does the same thing as `ò4`, except returning only the first item; strangely, it doesn't seem to be documented)

Comment: @ETHproductions Thanks for making Japt!

Comment: _Finally_ got around to that shorter version - only took 3 years! https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/211146/58974

Answer (score 6):

### Ruby, <s>65</s> <s>63</s> 60 bytes

```ruby
->s{s.split.map{|x|x.gsub(/..../){$&.ord%5}.to_i(2).chr}*''}
```

This is an anonymous proc that takes input and gives output as a string.

```ruby
->s{
s.split            # split on whitespace
.map{|x|           # for each word as x,
  x.gsub(/..../){  # replace each sequence of four characters with
    $&.ord%5       # the ASCII value of the first character, mod 5
                   # F is 70, B is 66, so this yields 0 for Fizz and 1 for Buzz
  }.to_i(2)        # interpret as a binary number
  .chr             # the character with this ASCII value
}*''               # join on empty string
}
```

Answer (score 6):

## JavaScript (ES6), <s>95</s> <s>88</s> <s>85</s> 81 bytes

```
s=>s.replace(/..zz/g,m=>m<"F"|0).replace(/\d+ ?/g,m=>String.fromCharCode("0b"+m))
```

- 4 bytes saved thanks to [ETHproductions](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/42545/ethproductions).

---

### Try it

```js
f=
s=>s.replace(/..zz/g,m=>m<"F"|0).replace(/\d+ ?/g,m=>String.fromCharCode("0b"+m))
oninput=_=>o.innerText=f(i.value)
o.innerText=f(i.value="FizzBuzzBuzzFizzBuzzFizzFizzFizz FizzBuzzBuzzFizzBuzzFizzFizzBuzz FizzFizzBuzzFizzFizzFizzFizzBuzz")
```

```css
*{font-family:sans-serif}
```

```html
<input id=i><p id=o>
```

Comment: I believe `+` is shorter than `parseInt`

Comment: I think `+(m[0]<"F")` could be shortened to `m<"F"|0`

Answer (score 5):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>90</s> <s>83</s> <s>82</s> 81 bytes

<sup>-1 byte thanks to totallyhuman</sup>
<sup>-1 byte thanks to Martmists</sup>
<sup>-1 byte thanks to Jonathan Frech</sup>

```python
lambda x:''.join(chr(int(`[+(l<'D')for l in b[::4]]`[1::3],2))for b in x.split())
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fUvdCsIgFH6Vc3eOFINWV1I3MXoJEzYLmWEqZrD28paFsKsuPr7/8Eqjd23Wh3O2w11dB5g4YnPzxtFljGRcol6syO6xQ6Z9BAvGgRKc76TsxYbzrVy37FupUk3NI1iTiLEc4ucOmvBk5vn4/KHqwhXwb1A0LM3yWTNk@Q0)

Comment: [Sans a byte.](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/qfZhvzPycxNyklUaHCSl1dLys/M08jOaNIIzOvRCNPx0hTMy2/SCFPITNPoUKvKLUgJzE5VUPdLbOqSl1H3UBdEyHmVAoWMwSKFRfkZJZoaGr@LygCGqOQBtEAUgDCMDaIhmEFfApAbAVkDrJOmJi65n8A "Python 2 – Try It Online")

Comment: you can save a byte by turning `*1 for` into `*1for`

Comment: Since you use `*1` to convert from boolean to integer, you can save a byte by using a `+`: `(l<'D')*1for` can be `+(l<'D')for`.

Answer (score 5):

## Perl 5, 33 Bytes

```pl
print(pack'B*',<>=~y/FB -z/01/dr)
```

Replaces 'F' and 'B' in the input with 0 and 1 respectively, and deletes the other characters. It then uses perl's `pack` function to turn this bit string into ASCII characters.

Comment: Wow this is golfed down to about half the size of my Perl 5 attempt. Kudos.

Comment: I believe you could make this considerably shorter using the `-p0` command line option (which would save you `<>=~r` for input, and allow you to use `$_=` rather than `print()`). Depending on how you want to handle newlines, you might not even need the `0`. (Even if you want to avoid command line option penalties, `say` is shorter than `print`.)

Comment: @Chris Not mine, faubiguy's. But thanks. ;)

Comment: @DavidConrad My bad haha.

Comment: You definitely don't need the 0 either. Just use the -p flag and `$_=pack'B*',y/FB -z/01/dr` for your program lowers your score to 26 bytes.

Answer (score 3):

## [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/), <s>59</s> <s>57</s> 53 bytes

```matlab
@(s)['',bi2de(flip(reshape(s(65<s&s<71)<70,8,[]))')']
```

This doesn't work on TIO, since the communication toolbox is not implemented. It works fine if you copy-paste it to [Octave-online](http://octave-online.net/). It's not even close to be working code in MATLAB.

Managed to save two bytes by transposing the matrix after flipping it, instead of the other way around.

#### Explanation:

```matlab
@(s)             % Anonymous function that takes a string as input
    ['',<code>]  % Implicitly convert the result of <code> to its ASCII-characters
```

**Let's start in the middle of `<code>`:**

```matlab
s(65<s&s<71)      % Takes the elements of the input string that are between 66 and 70 (B and F)
                  % This gives a string FBBFFBBFBBBFFFBF...
s(65<s&s<71)<70   % Converts the resulting string into true and false, where F becomes false.
                  % Transformation: FBBFFB -> [0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1]
```

Let's call the resulting boolean (binary) vector for `t`.

```matlab
reshape(t,8,[])       % Convert the list of 1 and 0 into a matrix with 8 rows, one for each bit
flip(reshape(t,8,[])) % Flip the matrix vertically, since bi2de reads the bits from the wrong end
flip(reshape(t,8,[]))' % Transpose it, so that we have 8 columns, and one row per character
bi2de(.....)'          % Convert the result decimal values and transpose it so that it's horizontal
```

Answer (score 3):

## Whitespace, 123 bytes

Visible representation:

```
SSNNSSNSNSSSNSNSTNTSTTTSSSTSSSSSNTSSTSNSNTSSNSSSTSSTTSNTSSTNTSTNSSSTNTSSSNSSTNSSNSNSSNSTNTSTNTSTNTSTSSSNSNNNSSSNSNTTNSSNSNN
```

Unobfuscated program:

```
    push  0
loop:
    dup
    push  0
    dup
    ichr
    get
    push  32
    sub
    dup
    jz    space
    push  38
    sub
    jz    fizz
    push  1
    add
fizz:
    push  0
    dup
    dup
    ichr
    ichr
    ichr
    add
    jmp   loop
space:
    swap
    pchr
    jmp   loop
```

There's nothing particularly odd about the implementation, the only real golfing is in some strange reuse of temporaries as well as not caring about the unbounded stack growth to skim down some more bytes.

Answer (score 3):

## Perl 5, 28 bytes+4 bytes for flags=32 bytes

Run with the flags `-040pE`

```
$_=chr oct"0b".y/FB -z/01/dr
```

`-040` sets the record separator to a space so that perl sees each group of FizzBuzzes as a separate line, then loops over those lines, changing F to 0, B to 1, deleting everything else, then converting to binary and from there to ascii.

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 9 bytes

```
Ḳm€4=”BḄỌ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#@/9wx6bcR01rTGwfNcx1erij5eHunv///7tlVlU5lUIwjA2iYVgBnwIQGwA)

```
Ḳm€4=”BḄỌ  Main Link
Ḳ          Split on spaces
  €        Map
 m 4       Take every fourth letter (F and B)
    =”B    Check if each letter is equal to B (gives the binary representation)
       Ḅ   Binary -> Integer
        Ọ  Unord; gives chr(i)
```

-3 bytes thanks to Erik the Outgolfer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59508/discussion-between-erik-the-outgolfer-and-hyper-neutrino).

Answer (score 2):

## PHP, 67 Bytes

Limited to 8 letters

```
<?=hex2bin(dechex(bindec(strtr($argn,[Fizz=>0,Buzz=>1," "=>""]))));
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@G9jX5BRwKWSWJSeZ6vklllV5VQKwTA2iIZhBXwKQGwFZA6yTpiYkjWXvR3QUtuM1AqjpMw8jZTUZCBTA8gEsjSKS4pKijTArtGJBumxtTPQAemztTPUUVJQsrVTUorVBALr//8B)

## PHP, 77 Bytes

```php
foreach(explode(" ",strtr($argn,[Fizz=>0,Buzz=>1]))as$v)echo chr(bindec($v));
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@G9jX5BRwKWSWJSeZ6vklllV5VQKwTA2iIZhBXwKQGwFZA6yTpiYkvX/tPyi1MTkDI3UioKc/JRUDSUFJZ3ikqKSIg2wK3SiQWpt7Qx0QOpt7QxjNTUTi1XKNFOTM/IVkjOKNJIy81JSkzWAQprW//8DAA)

Answer (score 2):

## q/kdb+, <s>41</s> <s>40</s> <s>37</s> 33 bytes

**Solution:**

```
{10h$0b sv'66=vs[" ";x][;4*(!)8]}
```

**Example:**

```
q){10h$0b sv'66=vs[" ";x][;4*(!)8]}"FizzBuzzBuzzFizzBuzzFizzFizzFizz FizzBuzzBuzzFizzBuzzFizzFizzBuzz FizzFizzBuzzFizzFizzFizzFizzBuzz"
"hi!"
```

**Explanation:**

Split the input string on `" "` to give distinct lists of `FizzBuzz...`, index into each of these lists at the first character (ie `0 4 8 ... 28`). Return boolean list determined by whether each character is `"B"` (ASCII `66`). Convert these lists to base 10, and then cast result to string.

```
{10h$0b sv'66=vs[" ";x][;4*til 8]} / ungolfed solution
{                                } / lambda function with x as implicit input
              vs[" ";x]            / split (vs) input (x) on space (" ")
                           til 8   / til 8, the range 0..7 inclusive
                         4*        / vectorised multiplication, 0 1 2 3 => 0 4 8 12
                       [;       ]  / index the 2nd level at these indices (0, 4, 8 ... 28)
           66=                     / 66 is ASCII B, 66="FBBFBFFF" -> 01101000b
     0b sv'                        / join (sv) each row back with 0b (converts from binary)
 10h$                              / cast to ASCII (0x686921 -> "hi!")
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Brain-Flak](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/Brain-Flak), 107 bytes

```
{(((((()()()()){}){}){})({}[{}])()())((){[()](<{}>)}{}<>)<>{(<{}{}{}{}>)<>({}({}){})<>}{}}<>{({}<>)<>}<>
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMzTTctJzP7/v1oDDDQhULO6Foo0qmujq2tjIaJA@epoDc1YDZvqWjvN2upaGztNG7tqEBcCQVygDg2IXhs7oFAtSAFUJZD8/98ts6rKqRSCYWwQDcMK@BSA2P91kwE)

+3 bytes for the `-c` flag.

#### Explanation

```
{                                        For each character in input:
 (((((()()()()){}){}){})({}[{}])()())    Push 32-n and 66-n
 ((){[()](<{}>)}{}<>)<>                  If character is B, push 1 on second stack.  Otherwise, push 0
 {                                       If character is not space:
  (<{}{}{}{}>)                           Burn 3 additional characters
  <>({}({}){})<>                         Multiply current byte by 2 and add previously pushed bit
 }                                       (otherwise, the pushed 0 becomes the new current byte)
 {}                                      Remove character from input
}
<>{({}<>)<>}<>                           Reverse stack for output
```

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript ES6 - 98 bytes

**too many bytes, but at least readable**

Defined as function it is 98 bytes

```
let s=>s.replace(/(F)|(B)|./g,(c,F,B)=>B?1:F?0:'').replace(/.{8}/g,v=>String.fromCharCode('0b'+v))
```

**test:**

```
"FizzBuzzBuzzFizzBuzzFizzFizzFizz FizzBuzzBuzzFizzBuzzFizzFizzBuzz FizzFizzBuzzFizzFizzFizzFizzBuzz"
.replace(/(F)|(B)|./g,(c,F,B)=>F?0:B?1:'').replace(/.{8}/g,v=>String.fromCharCode('0b'+v))
```

#### Explanation:

```
/(F)|(B)|./
```

Matches the F and B letters and anything else as Groups

```
(c,F,B)=>F?0:B?1:''
```

is a Function that captures the groups , returns a 0 for F and 1 for B , or ''

c is the character matched
F and B are now Parameters!
the 3rd **.** group is ommitted as parameter

F and B are `undefined` when the 3rd group is matched
B is `undefined` when group F is matched

The resulting 0100.. etc string

is cut in slices of 8 bytes

```
.replace(/.{8}/g,v=>String.fromCharCode('0b'+v))
```

and processed as **0b** *binary* string

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! The objective of this challenge is to provide a program or function translating arbitrary FizzBuzz strings. I don' know much JavaScript, but a valid function submission might be `s=>s.replace( ...`. Also please do include a byte count in the Header of your answer.

Comment: I cleaned up some of your code formatting for you. Also, you don't need the `let`, anonymous functions are acceptable.

Answer (score 1):

### Haskell, 72 bytes

```
(>>= \w->toEnum(foldl1((+).(2*))[mod(fromEnum c)5|c<-w,c<'a']):"").words
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/haskell#@59mq2FnZ6sQU65rV5Lvmleaq5GWn5OSY6ihoa2pp2GkpakZnZufopFWlJ8LklVI1jStSbbRLddJtlFPVI/VtFJS0tQrzy9KKf6fm5iZp2CrUFCUmVeioKKQpqDklllV5VQKwTA2iIZhBXwKQGwFZA6yTpiY0n8A)

How it works

```
            words      -- split input string into words at spaces
(>>=      )            -- map the function to each word and flatten the resulting
                       -- list of strings into a single string
   \w->                -- for each word w
       [  |c<-w,c<'a'] -- take chars c that are less than 'a' (i.e. B and F)
     mod(fromEnum c)5  -- take ascii value of c modulus 5, i.e. convert to bit value
    foldl1((+).(2*))   -- convert list of bit to int
  toEnum(   ):""       -- convert ascii to char.  :"" forces toEnum to be of type String
                       -- now we have a list of single char strings, e.g. ["h","i","!"]
```

Answer (score 1):

## [shortC](//github.com/aaronryank/shortC), 35 bytes

```
i;AW*@&3?*@&9||(i+=i+*s%5):Pi),*s++
```

Conversions in this program:

- `A` - `int main(int argc, char **argv){`
- `W` - `while(`
- `@` - `argv`
- `P` - `putchar(`
- Auto-inserted `);}`

Heavily based off of [Doorknob's answer.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/123368/61563)

Answer (score 1):

## [APL (Dyalog Classic)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 17 bytes

```apl
{82⎕DR'B'=⍵∩'BF'}
```

### Explanation

```apl
           ⍵∩'BF'    cut, removes all but 'BF' from ⍵
       'B'=          equals 'B' turns it into binary stream   
 82⎕DR              converts into character stream
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNzkksLs5M/v@/2sLoUd9UlyB1J3XbR71bH3WsVHdyU6/FKaHulllV5VQKwTA2iIZhBXwKQGwFZA6yTpiYOgA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) [`-P`](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/), 9 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

Or [8 bytes](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=2.0a0&flags=LVA&header=dg&code=uMtuYmlmKWQ&input=IkZpenpCdXp6QnV6ekZpenpCdXp6Rml6ekZpenpGaXp6IEZpenpCdXp6QnV6ekZpenpCdXp6Rml6ekZpenpCdXp6IEZpenpGaXp6QnV6ekZpenpGaXp6Rml6ekZpenpCdXp6Ig) if input can be lowercase.

```
¸Ën"FB" d
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=2.0a0&flags=LVA&code=uMtuIkZCIiBk&input=IkZpenpCdXp6QnV6ekZpenpCdXp6Rml6ekZpenpGaXp6IEZpenpCdXp6QnV6ekZpenpCdXp6Rml6ekZpenpCdXp6IEZpenpGaXp6QnV6ekZpenpGaXp6Rml6ekZpenpCdXp6Ig)

```
¸Ën"FB" d     :Implicit input of string
¸             :Split on spaces
 Ë            :Map
  n"FB"       :  Convert from base "FB" to decimal, ignoring all other characters
        d     :  Get the character at that codepoint
              :Implicitly join and output
```

Answer (score 0):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 15 bytes

```
#vy„FBÃS'BQ2βçJ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f9fuazyUcM8N6fDzcHqToFG5zYdXu71/79bZlWVUykEw9ggGoYV8CkAsRWQOcg6YWIA)

Answer (score 0):

## Java 8, <s>117</s> 115 bytes

```
s->{for(String x:s.split(" "))System.out.print((char)Long.parseLong(x.replace("Fizz","0").replace("Buzz","1"),2));}
```

I doubt you can do a lot of the fancy regex replacements in Java like most other answers, mainly because you can't do anything with the captured capture-groups in Java-regexes.. (I.e. `"$1".charAt(...)` or `"$1".replace(...)` aren't possible for example.)

**Explanation:**

[Try it here.](https://tio.run/##fVA9bwIxDN35FVamWIKIdiwqQ4dOhYWxYnBDoKFHEsU5xIfut6cJ3KlMlfLk52fHec6ejjTxwbj95ifrhphhQdZdRwDWJRO3pA0sawpw9HYDWq5StG4HjLOidgXlcKJkNSzBwStknsyvWx@HztMLKw6NTVKAQFydOZmD8m1SodSTlPqbIn54t1OBIpvK5ElFE5ryuhTv9nIRYzEV@Ke9tTftSeD4GXHW5WomtF9NcdGbudk9lGV6H59rILxv4pS@j61jKgZe4wD4r6FyeEwebw6a6L@oy/kX)

```
s->{                          // Method with String parameter and no return-type
  for(String x:s.split(" "))  //  Loop over the input split by spaces:
    System.out.print(         //   Print:
     (char)                   //    Each character
     Long.parseLong(          //    after we've converted each binary-String to a long
      x.replace("Fizz","0").replace("Buzz","1")
                              //    after we've replaced the Fizz/Buzz to 0/1
     ,2));
}                             // End of method
```

Answer (score 0):

## Google Sheets, 94 bytes

```
=ArrayFormula(JOIN("",CHAR(BIN2DEC(SPLIT(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"Fizz",0),"Buzz",1)," ")))))
```

I'm not familiar with FizzBuzz binary but it seems that they're delineated by spaces so this formula relies on that. The logic is pretty simple:

- Replace `Fizz` with `0` and `Buzz` with `1`
- Split the result into an array using a space as a delimiter
- Convert each element from binary to decimal
- Replace each element with its ASCII equivalent
- Join each element without a delimiter

Answer (score 0):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 20 bytes

```
a.{~_8#.\2-.~'FB'i.]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/r/P81WTyFRr7ou3kJZL8ZIV69O3c1JPVMv9n9qcka@Qpq6W2ZVlVMpBMPYIBqGFfApALEVkDnIOmFi6v8B)